# SELECT statement inside another SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables called `messages` and `users`. In the `messages` table, there's a field which is a foreign key to the `users` table that is basically the users ID. I am trying to retrieve results from the `messages` table using a SELECT query, but I want the users username rather than their user ID. This SQL is wrong but I think it gets across the idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT (SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE u_id=?), message, sent FROM `messages` WHERE r_id=? AND sent > ?
```

Basically, I want to use the users ID stored in the `messages` table to get the users username to be returned AND get results from the `messages` table in one query.

I think JOINs are the tool for this, but I have very little bar no SQL experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to JOIN the two tables together, using the common u_id column.

```
SELECT u.username, m.message, m.sent
    FROM messages m
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON m.u_id = u.u_id 
    WHERE m.r_id = ?
        AND m.sent > ?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the case for an `inner join`:

```
select
    u.username,
    m.message,
    m.sent
from
    messages m
    inner join users u on
        m.u_id = u.u_id
where
    m.r_id = ?
    and u.u_id = ?
    and m.sent > ?
```

What you're doing here is taking the `messages` table and saying, "Okay, grab me everything in the `users` table where the `u_id` column from `messages` equals the `u_id` column from `users`.

The `where` clause then filters your results down based on the parameters you want to pass it.

You can join tables ad nauseum, so you don't have to do just one, for future reference.

If you'd like to read more about joins and the different types, I highly encourage you to read Atwood's post on it [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: I don't think the `and u.u_id = ?` is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables like this too:

```
SELECT 
    u.username, 
    m.message, 
    m.sent 
FROM 
    messages m,
    users u
WHERE 
    m.r_id=? AND 
    m.sent > ? AND
    m.u_id = u.u_id
```

m.u_id is user id in messages table

Comment: I would *strongly* discourage you from using this older, implicit JOIN style.

Comment: I agree with @JoeStefanelli. You're creating a `cross join` and then filtering the results here. This is not the way to write clear, readable, and maintainable code.

Comment: well, some of us are old school and still use it. :) but I agree, using JOINs are far better then my example

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the query slightly like this:

```
select 
    u.username, 
    m.message, 
    m.sent 
from 
    (
        select u_id,message,sent
        from messages
        where r_id = ?
        and sent > ?
    ) m 
    inner join 
    (
        select u_id,username
        from users
        where u_id = ?
    ) u using (u_id);
```

You need to make sure you have a compound index on r_id and sent

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD INDEX (r_id,sent);
```

Comment: Sure, I guess you could, but why in the heck would you want to?

Comment: In case the tables are huge, the refactored query only joins the needed data from each table. Written the other way, the temp table resulting from the cartesian product of `messsages` and `users` is then scanned to fulfill the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs only slight correction and then it's equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`, exactly as @Joe Stefanelli's answer if `messages.u_id` is never `NULL`):

```
SELECT
      (SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE u_id = messages.u_id) AS username
     , message
     , sent 
FROM messages  
WHERE r_id = ? 
  AND sent > ?
```